Create logic app to trigger mail alert (secret, certificate, keys) which is expire in next 30 days from all the subscription within tenant
I am beginner in Logic apps and Kusto. My requirement is Create logic app to trigger mail alert (secret, certificate, keys) which is about to expire in next 30 days from all the subscription within tenant. I need details workflow and code along with it. Thanks
Hello Team, I am beginner in Logic apps and Kusto. My requirement is Create logic app to trigger mail alert (secret, certificate, keys) which is about to expire in next 30 days from all the subscription within tenant. I need details workflow and code along with it. Thanks I will look forward
I was tried How to Send Email Notifications for Key Vault Expiration Dates 30 Days in Advance Using Logic App Flows? but doesn't work

You should consider using Azure Monitor Log Alerts for this , this is much simpler solution than using custom logic apps
